# Is it safe to include username and password in readfile URL?

Tags: php, readfile

I want to fetch a file from an FTP server to the client directly. But the FTP connection needs to be authenticated. 
This is what I have:

```
readfile("ftp://$ftp_username:$ftp_password@$ftp_server/$filename");
```

It works as expected. But, I was wondering if there are any security risks. Are there ways the users can access the username and password?

Comment: Sure, one slight server misconfiguration which causes your source code to "leak" and now everyone can see all the usernames/passwords you've embedded in the code.

Comment: who is not using Sftp theses days ?

Comment: Suggestion: use environment variables ($_ENV) to get the username/password and merge them in the vars. Otherwise, fetch them from DB and do the same.

Comment: `ftp` is inherently insecure, but it would require someone snooping on the servers local network to make it a problem. Your client should not see anything related to it, _provided_ you set `display_errors` to _off_ in production, so a connect error doesn't show that client to what server you couldn't connect just now.

Comment: Anyone with file access (such as maliciously gaining access to the server) will also open access to that ftp server... unless that ftp is a read-only user. error reporting should be turned off if you take this route, though.

Comment: Thanks guys. I switched to sftp. The user login is stored in a file outside of root.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to think about is *where* that password might be visible. There are three places I can spot:

1. Wherever that `$ftp_password` variable is coming from (a config file, hard-coded in the PHP, a database, ...). Compromise that, and you have the password. Anywhere you store it will be readable, because you have to read it, but you could store parts in different places - an encrypted password in the DB, and the encryption key on disk.
2. In the running PHP code itself. This is pretty tricky to guard against if you're using any kind of password, but if the attacker can run arbitrary PHP code on your server, you're already in big trouble. Just make sure you don't echo out arbitrary bits of PHP code in things like error messages on your production server.
3. In the FTP traffic itself. FTP is one of the oldest protocols in the Internet, and is inherently insecure in the way it transmits passwords. If you control the server, you could use FTPS or FTPES, which are security extensions a bit like HTTPS is to HTTP; or you could switch instead to SFTP, which despite the name is a completely different protocol where files are transmitted using an SSH connection. SFTP (since it's based on SSH) can also support key-based authentication, rather than just a password, although you still need to store a private key somewhere.